HomePod "Alarm" doesn't work reliably
I'm trying to set an "alarm" for the house on my HomePod mini. I created an Automation that at time X → Accessory HomePod → Media Play Audio (Ambient Sounds Forest)
After it was created, for the first few days it didn't fire at all. One time I saw on the Home app that the Apple TV was playing Forest. Then on Friday it went off, but not since then.
I suppose my questions are:

Why doesn't the alarm work?
If HomePod automations are unreliable, how can I achieve a similar effect?

